Can any analytic function be written as the difference of two monotonically increasing analytic functions?
This question is not a duplicate of this one or this one, since the solutions shown there contain jumps.
Let $f(x)$ be an analytic function on $\mathbb{R}$. We can take its Taylor series and group the terms with a positive coefficient in one function $f_+(x)$ and terms with a negative coefficient in a function $f_-(x)$. Then $f(x) = f_+(x) - f_-(x)$, both components are monotonically rising on $\mathbb{R}_+$, and both are analytic. However, at $0$ the components would have to swap to maintain monotonicity, creating a discontinuity. Can this be avoided?
For an easier question, consider specifically the case of $f(x) = x^2$. I can't even find a simple decomposition for this basic case. I'm not convinced it exists -- this is not homework, I have no idea which way the truth lies.

"However, at $0$ the components would have to swap to maintain monotonicity, creating a discontinuity": Do you mean a discontinuity in some derivative? The functions themselves could be continuous, I think. For example, in $f (x) = x^2$, you could take $f_- (x) = \begin{cases} -x^2 & x \le 0 \ 0 & x > 0 \end{cases}$ and $f_+ (x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \le 0 \ x^2 & x > 0 \end{cases}$ (of course, these are not analytic, but they are continuous and monotonic).

$x^2 = (x^3 + x^2 + x) - (x^3 + x)$

One way to solve this is to construct an increasing analytic function $g$ so that $f+g$ is also increasing. For that to hold, we need $g'(x)\ge\max(0, -f'(x))$.
Let
$$
g(x) = \int_0^x h\left(f'(t)\right)\,dt
$$
where $h$ is an analytical function with $h(u)>\max(0,-u)$: eg $h(u)=\sqrt{1+u^2}$. This makes $g$ analytical and increasing, and $f'(x)+g'(x)>0$ so that $f+g$ is too.

Both answers are very nice; I chose to accept this one because it slightly better motivates the construction. Thanks!

Define two new analytic functions
$$
g(x) = \int_0^x (1+f'(t)^2)\,dt \quad\text{and}\quad h(x) = g(x) + f(x).
$$
Then certainly $f(x) = h(x)-g(x)$; and
$$
g'(x) = 1+f'(x)^2 > 0 \quad\text{and}\quad h'(x) = 1+f'(x)^2 + f'(x) = \tfrac34 + (f'(x)+\tfrac12)^2 > 0,
$$
so both functions are increasing.
